# Storing results of if a point is in a polygon in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to determine if a geometry point from PointTable is inside a polygon that is stored in PolygonTable. The two tables are linked by Id. I need the query to check each xy point where the Id's from the two table are equal. I want to store the results (of if the point is in the polygon) in the table with the geometry point under a new column IsInBox1 and IsInBox2. I think the function I need to use is STContains. I've illustrated the two tables as PolygonTable and PointTable. I use the word polygon to represent the actual polygon data and I used the letters xy to represent the point data.

PolygonTable

| Id | Box1 | Box2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | polygon | polygon |
| 2 | polygon | polygon |

PointTable

| Id | RowId | XY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xy |
| 1 | 2 | xy |
| 1 | 3 | xy |
| 2 | 1 | xy |
| 2 | 2 | xy |

This should be the result after the query.

PointTable

| Id | RowId | XY | IsInBox1 | IsInBox2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xy | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | xy | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | xy | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | xy | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | xy | 1 | 0 |

Here's some code of what I've tried. I am using SQL Server. Thanks.

```
SELECT Id, Box1, Box2
FROM PolygonTable
WHERE Box1.STContains(Select XY From PointTable)
) = 1 AS IsInBox1;
```

Comment: I added some code of what I've tried. It doesn't work and I thought it might be easier to just start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    PointTable.Id,
    PointTable.RowId,
    PointTable.XY,
    PolygonTable.Box1.STContains(PointTable.XY),
    PolygonTable.Box2.STContains(PointTable.XY)
FROM PolygonTable
INNER JOIN PointTable ON PointTable.Id=PolygonTable.Id
```

This is assuming you want to match the 2 tables based on the Id columns.

In this case, STContains is passes a single point as at time and returns a bit - true/false - is in/is not it.